# Run processing in separated thread by group

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, system.reactive, rx.net

I'm trying to use Rx in my Kafka consumer.

```
public static event EventHandler<ConsumeResult<string, string>> GenericEvent;
```

then I have the following code

```
var observable = Observable.FromEventPattern<ConsumeResult<string, string>>(
     x => GenericEvent += x,
     x => GenericEvent -= x)
  .Select(x => x.EventArgs);

while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    ConsumeResult<string, string> consumeResult = _consumer.Consume(cancellationToken);
    GenericEvent(consumeResult.Topic, consumeResult);
}
```

then somewhere I use it like

```
var subscription = observable.Subscribe(message =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} ** {message.Topic}/{message.Partition} @{message.Offset}: '{message.Value}'");

    //_kafkaConsumer.Commit(messages);
});
```

Are the any possibility to run separated thread by topic name (`consumeResult.Topic`)? When consumer receive a message, it should redirect it to the corresponding thread by topic

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1))
    .Take(20)
    .GroupBy(x => x % 3)
    .SelectMany(xs => Observable.Using(() => new EventLoopScheduler(), els => xs.ObserveOn(els)))
    .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x} {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"));
```

This ensures that a thread is created in the `new EventLoopScheduler()` scheduler for each inner observable created by the `GroupBy` operator. The `SelectMany` flattens out the group, but keeps the `EventLoopScheduler` associated for each group.

In your case you `GroupBy` the `consumeResult.Topic` property.

Do make sure that your source observable ends as the threads live forever until they do. Calling `Dispose()` on the subscription is sufficient to end the observable.

Comment: Wow, you are superman! Thanks. Could you please explain this a little bit more  "Do make sure that your source observable ends as the threads live forever until they do"

Comment: @Chebur - The `Observable.Using(() => new EventLoopScheduler(), els => xs.ObserveOn(els))` code creates a new thread with each `new EventLoopScheduler()`. Those threads do not exit until each `EventLoopScheduler` 
 has `Dispose()` called on it. That happens when the outer observable finishes. In my example I've used `Take(20)` to make it naturally stop after `20` elements, but if you don't have a natural end then you need to dispose the subscription to make it end and that with allow the new threads to exit naturally.

Comment: Thanks. How can I use values of `ConsumeResult<string, string>` in my case in subscribe method? It seems I need some logic there instead of Console.WriteLine, right? Or processing logic should be in other place?

Comment: ohh I found, it is `x.EventArgs`

Comment: @Chebur - You haven't explained what you're doing with your code so it's hard to say what is exactly the right thing to do, but you have the choice of using a `.Select`, `.Do`, or `.Subscribe` to do your processing.

Comment: Need you help. It create a separate thread per group. In Subscribe() I added `Thread.Sleep(10000);` to emulate long processing. But it runs for 1st group, sleep, then run for the next one. How can I run it in parallel? Each groups has own thread (A and B), processing should start in parallel for A and B, but inside A message process one by one. Sorry it is difficult to explain. Please ask me for more details

Comment: @Chebur - That's what Rx does. It's only meant to do one thing at a time. What you can do is move the work inside the `SelectMany` as a `Select` after the `ObserveOn`. That'll let them run in parallel.